# Why does 7.6Mhz signal start appearing?

Tags: inductor, capacitance, circuit-design, signal-integrity, resonance

I am using a reference design that modulates a 8Mhz carrier DC square wave in simple on-off keying at 10bps. 
[image]
I wanted to change the carrier to 125kHz. I took out the 56pF capacitor in C4 and soldered in a 330nF capacitor hoping it would resonate at 125khz. Instead a 7.6Mhz signal showed up inside the pulse of my 125kHz square wave. You can see it start to appear when I go below 1Mhz modulation in the photo. (This is 900kHz) 
 [image]
Where does it come from and how do I get rid of it? The PIC uC is running at 8Mhz so I thought it was coupling, but the reference design companion board runs at 125kHz modulation and doesn't have this problem.

Here is my simulation in LTSpice. This is what I thought would happen. I soldered in a .33uF cap but measured .45uF with my multimeter.
[image]

Comment: You are dropping a 8MHZ carrier down to 125KHZ?. Did you think it would be that easy? 8MHZ means more than one part is designed for that frequency. You are getting a beat frequency due to incompatibility. The osc may not be able to run at such a low frequency in a stable manor.

Comment: I configured the PIC to use a pin as input for the carrier. The signal is coming from a signal generator. Could this be reflections?

Comment: Very possibly. Do you have a VSW meter? A dummy load? A series resistor for impedance matching?

Comment: No, I don't have a VSWR meter unfortunately. The "antenna" is a copper plane 4cmx2cm. I could put the resistor at the feed point and ground. I have to figure out how to calculate it.

Comment: Why bother using the original RF stuff? 125 kHz is so low that you can probably configure a PIC timer/divider to take the 8 MHz clock divide by 64 and spit out exactly 125 kHz on a pin, then bit-bang modulate that at 10 bps.

Comment: It is a BodyCom Kit that capacitively couples to a person. It uses a copper pour as the coupling element and I treat it like an antenna. I need the tank circuit to up the voltage.

Comment: Only adjusting the capacitor value significantly alters the Q of the circuit. Try making both L and C proportionatly bigger to suit 125 kHz. Also it's Hz, kHz or MHz.

Comment: Andy, what do you mean by Hz, kHz, or Mhz?